# beveling with an angle

Tags: modeling

I'm needing help oh how to recreate this bevel edge so it is wider on one end of the edge and the bevel will be smaller on the other end. In the image I drew on you can ignore the red area but I'm confused on how to make the yellow area on one edge of a cube. Can you help me out, pls?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't swear this is the snappiest way, but in order to keep the sides of the  bevelled projection absolutely flush with the sides of the cube , I found it best to best to work to a reference-point: the missing corner.

[image]

- A Bisect operation on the default cube, center (.4,.4,.4) normal (1,1,1)
- Triangular face filled, Custom Orientation created from it.
- With Object Mode Option > 'Origins' checked, the object axes moved to the triangle,  and with Header > Object > Transform .. aligned to the 'Face' transform orientation
- The Empty parented to the object, and <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>G</kbd>, the object oriented to the world and centered.

[image]

- Cursor to the Empty, set as Transform Pivot Point
- <kbd>Y</kbd> the triangle split off
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>B</kbd>, (or a modifier), its corners bevelled, with an even number of segments
- The rounded triangle <kbd>E</kbd> extruded, the extrusion right-click dropped in place, and then <kbd>S</kbd> scaled towards the cursor.
- Bottom face deleted.

I hope that's the step you're looking for. The rest is cutting edges to create vertices to stitch everything together, bridging edge-loops, the cube-edges bevelled with a matching segment-count, support loops. Some of the work can be done under a 3-way rotational *Array* modifier, to ensure all corners match.

[image]

Comment: I think I did ur process right. It was confusing, I did do some things differently, like I didn't do the bisect thing. Instead, I beveled the vertices. Then I couldn't understand ur 3rd image so I separated the face 2 a new object and beveled the 3 vertices, then I extruded it up like u did. Then I joined it back with the original cube & now it looks like this image (https://ibb.co/FmXybKC) but I can't seem 2 get the same look as u did. I beveled some edges cause on a real corner piece there is different edge bevels but when I use the subdivided modifier it looks like this & it's awful

Comment: subdivide modifier (https://ibb.co/P60xwNv)
Here is my blend file if you wanted to see how it looks. I'm not sure how to get the little triangle parts to look like yours where the tapered bevel meets the cube at. (https://pasteall.org/blend/86f7541d429d4f389fe2ae7e58564ff9)

Comment: See [here](https://imgur.com/a/VApO3gG) To get the cube to marry with the extrusion, I bevelled the edge in the green circle with the same number of segments as the others at the same time, and bridged the edge loops across the gap between the red arrows. Other cuts in the cube are needed at the _ends_ of those bevels, to get the sides of the cube to fully stitch up. I won't deny it's fiddly. If I were to make a full step-by-step, it would be a very long answer, I may be wrong, but I don't think the hand-work is avoidable. Someone may prove me wrong :)

Comment: I should have shown the line in the screenshot, this is what I had shown. (https://ibb.co/CsyD97H) I'm a visual person so I'm not sure if I understand what you're saying by what I'm reading but so I deleted the triangle faces in between your red arrows and just beveled the edge in the green circle you made. I then reconnected the edges with the F key and now this is what it looks like (https://ibb.co/hDJGF77) and this is what the one side look like with the modifier on (https://ibb.co/HFNM8rB) It's still not like your example but its kinda getting there. Am I close to understanding it.

Comment: @AlexWillis21  Yup. So far so good. I don't think, though, the sides of the cube are welded to the extrusion yet. See [here](https://imgur.com/a/LsS4hJJ). There needs to be some kind of cut (blue line) to make a vertex in the side of the cube, which can be  welded to the extrusion. Set your snap to 'Vertex' and 'Active' to help out, and possibly set 'Auto Merge Vertices' to weld.  You just have to be careful not to move the vertices which define the cube-side plane.. The whole object can be split 3 ways and reassembled with a rotational array, so you only have to do this once.

Comment: Would you be willing to make a short video just of how you make it so I can visually see it? You don't need to explain it in the video or even have audio I'm just a visual learner and I'm not understanding most of what you're saying because written instructions are like a foreign language to me, :) if you can't, it's ok too.

Comment: I'm ashamed I'm not really set up for video ... I'll share the file ... I could try recreating one with all the steps. See if this one helps, first: https://pasteall.org/blend/9bd6ad97e3ab409ab246c8b31bfb1b5f

Comment: Wow, I can see where some of my problems were now comparing your model to mine. Thank you. I will dissect it and study just how you were able to make this and make my own from your example. Thank you so much.

Comment: @AlexWillis21 np. If you need some steps, just drop us a line.